# Apply pre format on selected text tinymce

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am working on tinymce and facing one issue. Whenever I want to apply any format to selected text e.g pre, block etc, It does apply to all the line not only the selected text.

[image]

In above example, i am applying preformatted text to "the demo is to show the integration", however, it will be applied to the full line. Can I modify this default behavior?

```
tinymce.init({
 selector: 'textarea',
 height: 500,
 menubar: false,
 plugins: [
'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor textcolor',
'searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen',
'insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste code help wordcount'
],
toolbar: 'insert | undo redo |  formatselect | bold italic backcolor  |    alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | removeformat | help',
 content_css: [
'//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
'//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css']
 });
```

https://codepen.io/tinymce/pen/YydQrY

Answer (score 1):

The element you are using to do this is designed to change the formatting of the block element.  When you select any of those options its changing the surrounding block element - that is simply how that works.

You can write your own custom toolbar button to do what you want.  Please see this TinyMCE Fiddle for an example:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/1igaab/1

The key is this function in the editor setup:

```
editor.addButton('wrapinpre', {
   text: 'Wrap in PRE',
   icon: false,
   onclick: function () {
     editor.insertContent("<pre>" + editor.selection.getContent() + "</pre>");
   }
}
```

Please note that when you do this, TinyMCE knows that PRE is a block tag and will clean up the surrounding HTML so you still have valid blocks before and after the PRE section.

Answer (score 1):

These line of codes will replace existing selected content and append with `<pre>` tag with selected text:

```
editor.addButton('addpretag', { text: 'Add PRE tag',   onclick: function () {
    var text = tinyMCE.activeEditor.selection.getContent();
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceReplaceContent', false, "<pre>" + text + "</pre>");
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you, +Balakrishnan .s. Just i want to confirm, if we can add this click option to Format Options? 

I want same to happen on code block format {title: 'Blocks', items: [
            {title: 'Paragraph', format: 'p'},
            {title: 'Blockquote', format: 'blockquote'},
            {title: 'Div', format: 'div'},
            {title: 'Pre', format: 'pre'},
   {title : 'Code', block : 'pre', classes : 'ckeditor_codeblock', exact: true},
   {title : 'Fixed Width', inline : 'span', classes : 'fixed_width', exact: true}
        ]}